# Mobile version of a CSS/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, html, mobile

I have a web sketch I programmed with HTML5, CSS and JavaScript that I'd like to have in another mobile/tablet version.
Since I'm a bit oldschool, I'm not familiar with bringing it to a mobile form.

Any ideas on how to make this happen?

Comment: What do you mean by "mobile form" actually? HTML should work fine with mobile devices, atleast to some extent(when they aren't responsive).

Comment: What I mean is I'll be able to see the website in it's mobile version. A new layout of the menu/banner/etc without having any spaces in the left/right sides

Comment: You can add responsiveness by using famous responsive frameworks, or code one on your own(tedious process)

Comment: Oh I see.. I'll look into that! Thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I presume that you might be looking for converting plain HTML into responsive ones. You might achieve it by using the famous [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) framework, or any other alternatives.

Comment: I wouldn't jump to Bootstrap straight away. Consider using native CSS media queries to add breakpoints to your code. You don't want to attach a large library to accomplish a small task.

Comment: Yes, me neither but `I have a web sketch I programmed with HTML5, CSS and JavaScript` sounds like he already have a big website, and I thought that using bootstrap would be the preferred choice

Comment: Yep, I agree, it's a good idea to provide the option for those who need it.